# Adding & removing function from typed.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, typed.js

**I'm using the typed.js plugin to add some typing text to a site I'm working on.** My question is this:

In typed.js, theres a function called 'humanize' that adds a random element to how text is typed out.

```
var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + this.typeSpeed;
```

I want to make sentences 'type' out with humanize, but backspace without it. I'm looking at the typed.js documentation, and I feel like there should be a simple way to this, but I'm stuck on where to begin. Any advice/help/constructive criticism is much appreciated!

Comment: do you want the backspacing to be as fast as possible or at a fixed rate?

Comment: Fixed rate is what I'm looking for, yes!